# Saving classification keras model to output the category name

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification

I've created a model that outputs the category name of some image (and not the probabilities)

I want to save the model so the user will be able to load it, and use it to predict the category of a particular image. I don't want the user to know how many classes I can predict, in other words, I don't want to provide the user a list of classes and their "labels" so he'll index it.

I've appended my model as follows:

```
labels = Lambda(lambda x: K.argmax(x, axis=-1))(model.output)
categories = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(classes, x))(labels)
final_model = Model(model.input, categories)
```

where

```
classes=["dog", "cat", ... , "table"]
```

I'm saving this model using `mode.save` method, but when I want to load the model, I must provide it the `custom_objects` :( as follows:

```
load_model("test.h5", custom_objects={"tf": tf, "classes": classes})
```

Is there a way to avoid it?